# Apply function too slow in r

Tags: r, loops, apply

I have to calculate for a lot of species a specific formula per row. The formula is a product between a value of abundance and a value present in the last row of the data frame. Then, all these products are summed.

My current script consists in using an apply function which appears to be as slow as the for-loop I started with.
I simplified the problem in the following script, using a simple df called `az` :

```
az=data.frame(c(1,2,10),c(2,4,20),c(3,6,30))
colnames(az)=c("a","b","c")


# Initial for loop
prov=0 # prov for provisional number
    for (i in 1:nrow(az)){
            for (j in 1:ncol(az)){
                   prov=prov+az[i,j]*az[nrow(az),j]
            }
        print(prov)
        prov=0
        }

# Apply solution
apply(az[,], 1, function(x) {sum(x*az[nrow(az),], na.rm=TRUE)})
```

Both solutions work but they are quite slow (with my original df) and I have to repeat the operation for a huge number of species.
Thus, I was wondering if anyone has a more efficient solution, maybe using vectorized expressions.

Kind regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fastest solution is probably matrix algebra:

```
apply(az[,], 1, function(x) {sum(x*az[nrow(az),], na.rm=TRUE)})
#[1]  140  280 1400

m <- as.matrix(az)
m[is.na(m)] <- 0 #remove NA from sums
as.vector(m %*% m[nrow(m),])
#[1]  140  280 1400
```

Comment: `tcrossprod` might be a bit faster `as.vector(tcrossprod( m[nrow(m),],m))`

Comment: @akrun In general yes, but I'm not so sure if it offers benefits in this specific case where one factor is just a vector.

Comment: I got a toughest one for you (but I can't edit my initial post). Instead of doing `prov=prov+az[i,j]*az[nrow(az),j]` in the initial for loop, I have to do `prov=prov+az[i,j]*(az[nrow(az),j-m[])^2]` with m[] the result we got per row in the initial post. It's actually a variance calculation (and the first corresponded to a mean). Am I clear enough ?

Comment: Please ask a new question.

Comment: Ok, here is the link : [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29128432/optimize-variance-calculation-for-loop-too-slow]

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
  rowSums(az*unlist(az[nrow(az),])[col(az)], na.rm=TRUE)
```

Or a slightly faster option would be to use `rep`

```
  rowSums(az*rep(unlist(az[nrow(az),]),each=ncol(az)), na.rm=TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanl you very much for the answer. The matrix algebra version is a bit faster however.

Comment: @user3443183 No problem.  I would also the matrix algebra