# Optimize variance calculation, for loop too slow

Tags: r, for-loop

Here is the next step of the question answered at this link [[Apply function too slow in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29125609/apply-function-too-slow-in-r][1])

I have to calculate for a lot of species a specific formula per row. The formula correspond to a variance calculation and so need the result obtained in the above link.

My current script consists in using a for-loop which is naturally very slow. I simplified the problem in the following script, using a simple df called `az`.

```
az=data.frame(c(1,2,10),c(2,4,20),c(3,6,30))
colnames(az)=c("a","b","c")

# Necessary number calculated in step 1 (see link above)
m <- as.matrix(az)
m[is.na(m)] <- 0 #remove NA from sums
step1 = as.vector(m %*% m[nrow(m),])

# Initial for loop
prov=0 # prov for provisional number
    for (i in 1:nrow(az)){
            for (j in 1:ncol(az)){
                   prov=prov+az[i,j]*az[nrow(az),j]
                   prov=prov+az[i,j]*(az[nrow(az),j]-step1[i])^2
            }
        print(prov)
        prov=0
        }
```

As I have to repeat the operation for a huge number of species, I was wondering if anyone has a more efficient solution, maybe using vectorized expressions.

Kind regards.

Comment: Code optimization questions should be asked on CodeReview rather than StackOverflow http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Hack-R Do you have a relevant meta question to back up that claim?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will return the same values that your code prints out, but more efficiently.

```
> n<-nrow(m)
> mm<-t(m)
> prov<-mm*mm[,n]
> prov<-prov+mm*(mm[,n]-step1[col(mm)])^2
> colSums(prov)
[1]     82140    791480 113717400
```

Comment: It works except that the code line : `prov<-mm*mm[,n]` seems useless. Thanks a lot for the transposition idea !